# Is there any way to get a method's return value without running the rest of its code?

Tags: java, validation, methods, return

Curious if there is a way to skip a method's code and only grab the return value. Right now this example code will run call `choices()` twice while I only want its `return` value when sending it as a parameter to the         `Input.validate(...)` method.

I know I don't have to strictly keep all the valid choices with the `choices()` method but it definitely seems cleaner to keep them grouped together.

```
public class Display
{
     public static String[] choices()
     {
          System.out.println("Choices:");
          System.out.println("A. foo");
          System.out.println("B. bar");

          String[] validChoices = {"A", "B"};
          return validChoices;
     }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
          String input;
          Display.choices(); //Called to output valid choices

          input = in.nextLine();
          Input.validate(input, Display.choices()); 

          //Sends "input" to be compared with all the values in "validChoices" array
          //returned by "choices()" method but also duplicates output
     }
}
```

Mainly a matter of efficiency and not making a new `getChoices()` method for every unique group of choices I want to display and validate the input thereafter.

Also curious what other kinds of workarounds there might be just in terms of keeping code more concise and efficient.

Comment: what about `String[] choices = Display.choices();`?

Comment: So you want to have the return value and skip the `sout` calls?

Comment: @WalterM That would still display the `System.out.println(...)` calls

@DrewKennedy Yes.

Comment: @WalterM Woops, misunderstood what you meant by that. I see what I have to do now.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot skip method's printing and other side effects without some assistance from the method. For example, you could pass it something to indicate that no output should be performed:

```
 public static String[] choices(boolean performOutput) {
     if (performOutput) {
         System.out.println("Choices:");
         System.out.println("A. foo");
         System.out.println("B. bar");
      }
      String[] validChoices = {"A", "B"};
      return validChoices;
 }
```

Now you can call `Display.choices(true)` to have output and `Display.choices(false)` to produce no output.

However, it is not necessary in your case: when the method returns the same thing every time you run it, you could call it, store its output, and use stored output from that point on:

```
String choices = Display.choices(); //Called to output valid choices
input = in.nextLine();
Input.validate(input, choices);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want one method to do two different things:

1. Return an array and perform `System.out.println()` calls
2. Return the array only and skip the `System.out.println()` calls

One way to achieve this is to give the method a `boolean` parameter as a flag:

```
public static String[] choices(boolean returnArrayOnly) {
    if (!returnArrayOnly) {
        System.out.println("Choices:");
        System.out.println("A. foo");
        System.out.println("B. bar");
    }
    return new [] {"A", "B"};//cut down from String[] validChoices = {"A", "B"};
 }
```